# Yii: PHP SOAP WSDL server with CWebService

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii, wsdl

I have the following web-service written in php:

```
$server = new SoapServer("WebService.wsdl");

$server->addFunction('perform');

$server->handle();



function perform($params) {

}
```

I would like to rewrite this in Yii using CWebservice, but I could not find any example using soap server with custom wsdl in the yii docs. Could you please help me to get started?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/46059-soap-web-service-server/

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=soap

Comment: @tinyByte Thanks for reply, but I know how to use Google. I said: I could not find any example using soap server with CUSTOM (COMPLEX) wsdl in the yii docs.

Comment: @jCloud did you implement soap server and client in yii?